# In shiny app, how to store user input/output for later use?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny-server, shiny

The user input a text.

Based on this text, my app makes a prediction **(KatzPred function)** and return a data.frame - which is updated every time the user input a word.

Thes data.frame returned by the function is something like this:

```
pred  PKatz

the     0.003
of      0.002
in      0.002
to      0.001
```

My server should take this prediction and compare to the user text and give as an output a data.frame and a plot.

here is my code, which is not working as expected (I am getting just the last prediction and not being able to use all predictions).

SERVER.R

```
teste<-reactive({
            KatzPred(input$userinput)
    })
 output$predTable<-renderDataTable({teste()})

prediction<-reactive({
  a<-c()
  a<-c(a,teste()$term[1])
  a
 })

newtext<-reactive({
            if (length(unlist(strsplit(input$userinput, " ")))>0){
               actual<-unlist(strsplit(input$userinput, " "))
               pred.data<-data.frame(pred = prediction() , actual = actual, correct = prediction()==actual)
               pred.data<-mutate(pred.data, accuracy = cumsum(correct)/1:nrow(pred.data))
            }else{

               pred.data<-data.frame(pred = "", actual = "")

            }
            pred.data
    })
output$accu<-renderDataTable({newtext()})
output$accu2<-renderPlot({
          (ggplot(data= newtext(),aes(x=1:nrow(newtext())))
            +geom_line(aes(y=accuracy, group=1))
             +geom_point(aes(y=accuracy)))
 })
```

The result I'm getting is something like:

User input : i am going out

```
pred     actual    correct    accuracy

to        i          FALSE      0
to        am         FALSE      0
to        going      FALSE      0
to        out        FALSE      0
```

When it should be (running on R):

```
pred     actual    correct    accuracy

the       i          FALSE      0
am        am         TRUE       0.5
very      going      FALSE      0.33
out       out        TRUE       0.5
```

This app is doing what I want to do in mine (it compares the user input with the history of predictions) in the lower right graph.

https://nate.shinyapps.io/DSCapstone/

Comment: How about giving us an entire runnable example? I know it is a bit of work but you are far more likely to get an answer that way.

Comment: I can't since I would have to post the Function Code...

Comment: I need to know how to make a vector composed of all the user input... and not just the last one...

Comment: So post the function code. Or a small version of it.

Comment: To save a variable between invocations try using the <<- operator.

Comment: Perhaps [shinyStore](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyStore)'s implementation of HTML5 LocalStorage would do what you want? It hasn't been touched in 2 years (and I don't use it), but perhaps it still works.

Comment: Interesting. Never heard of that one, will have to look into it.